# Micronaut controller with pagination using Pageable

Tags: pagination, controller, micronaut

I am trying to use a Micronaut controller with pagination. Micronaut-Data has [this Spring inspired way](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/latest/guide/index.html#pagination) to access the repositories using the [Pageable](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/latest/api/io/micronaut/data/model/Pageable.html) class and returning a [Page](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/latest/api/io/micronaut/data/model/Page.html)

The problem comes when you want to show this paginated data. I have not been able create a call the controller with pagination. Here I have a simple controller:

```java
    @Controller
    public class PageableController {

        private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PageableController.class);

        @Get(produces = APPLICATION_JSON, value = "/test{?pageable}")
        public Page<String> getNames(@Nullable Pageable pageable) {

            LOGGER.info("pageable {}", pageable);
            if( pageable == null){
                return Page.of(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar"), Pageable.UNPAGED, 2);
            }else{
                return Page.of(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar"), pageable, 2);
            }
        }
    }
```

I would expect to be able to call it with something like this. But currently the logger shows that pageable is always null:

```java
    @MicronautTest
    class PageableControllerTest {

        @Inject
        @Client("/")
        private RxHttpClient client;

        @Test
        void callsWithPageable() {
            String uri = "/test?size=20&number=2";
            String orders = client.toBlocking().retrieve(HttpRequest.GET(uri));

            //TODO, assert orders and pagination
        }
```

It would be even better if we could test it with something like:

```java
    @Test
    void callsWithPageableParsingJson() {
        String uri = "/test?size=20&number=2";

        //This fails to parse as it can't build pages.
        Page<String> pages = client.toBlocking().retrieve(HttpRequest.GET(uri), pageOf(String.class));

        assertThat(pages.getSize(),   is(2));
        assertThat(pages.getContent(), contains("foo", "bar"));
    }

    // Inspired by Argument.listOf
    private static <T> Argument<Page<T>> pageOf(Class<T> type) {
        return Argument.of((Class<Page<T>>) ((Class) Page.class), type);
    }
```

And this [Micronaut bug](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/981) shows that the right way to paginate is with Micronaut Data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was solved by adding the following dependecy:

```xml
    <dependency>
       <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
       <artifactId>micronaut-data-runtime</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.0.M1</version>
    </dependency>
```

My controller layer had access to the micronaut-data-model but this jar contains the important class [PageableRequestArgumentBinder](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/1.0.x/api/io/micronaut/data/runtime/http/PageableRequestArgumentBinder.html). Just by being i the classpath it will automatically be injected as a binder with no need for extra configuration.

And yes, Free See was right and now I can remove the pageable argument from the path and the argument from the method does not need to be @Nullable :

```java
    @Controller
    public class PageableController {

        private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PageableController.class);

        @Get(produces = APPLICATION_JSON, value = "/test")
        public Page<String> getNames(Pageable pageable) {

            LOGGER.info("pageable {}", pageable);
            return Page.of(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "baz"), pageable, 3);
        }
```

To call it we new to use the [standard parameters names](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/latest/api/constant-values.html#io.micronaut.data.runtime.config.DataConfiguration.PageableConfiguration.DEFAULT_PAGE_PARAMETER) defined in [DataConfiguration.PageableConfiguration](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/latest/api/io/micronaut/data/runtime/config/DataConfiguration.PageableConfiguration.html).

- DEFAULT_PAGE_PARAMETER   "page"
- DEFAULT_SIZE_PARAMETER   "size"
- DEFAULT_SORT_PARAMETER   "sort"

If you want to use different parameters you can change it with properties:

```
micronaut:
  data:
    pageable:
     max-page-size: 500
```

And you can test it with

```java
    @Test
    void callsWithPageable() {
        String uri = "/test?page=1&size=2";

        Page<String> pages = client.toBlocking().retrieve(HttpRequest.GET(uri), pageOf(String.class));

        assertThat(pages.getPageNumber(),   is(1));
        assertThat(pages.getTotalPages(),   is(2));
        assertThat(pages.getSize(),   is(2));
        assertThat(pages.getContent(), contains("foo", "bar", "baz"));
    }
```

And, to make things even better, the client can convert the result to a page using the pageOf method that returns Argument>

Answer (score 3):

In my application, I accept `Pageable` as well and I dont have any issues with it. The difference between mine and yours are:

1. My path is just `@Get("/test")` i.e. no `{pageable}` part.
2. I dont make my `Pageable` as `@Nullable`. From what I can trace from the micronaut code, it does not treat `Pageable` like any other object. It has special handling for it (like testing if the argument type is `Pageable` and if it is, then do certain things).

Can you try those two things?

Comment: May be I need to change something more because I get: io.micronaut.http.client.exceptions.HttpClientResponseException: Required argument [Pageable pageable] not specified

Answer (score 1):

`"/test{?pageable}"` Means to bind to a single query value called pageable

`"/test{?pageable*}"` Means to bind all query values to an argument called pageable

You want the latter

Comment: Hi James, I have just tested it and does not seems to work. It compiles but the received pageable argument is null.

Comment: That is definitely the way to go. There must be something else wrong with your app